# Unable to start ubuntu 15.04 in Virtual box

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

The installation went smoothly. But after the first reboot, the distro fails to startup. It is all I see in my screen

[image]

Virtual box version is 4.3.28 r100309 (Latest as of the time of writing)

Here is the vbox settings:

```
$ VBoxManage  showvminfo "LinuxDesktop15"                                                                                              
Name:            LinuxDesktop15
Groups:          /
Guest OS:        Ubuntu (64 bit)
UUID:            8bfd870e-f770-429d-bbfc-13b26dffc81d
Config file:     /Users/antkong/VirtualBox VMs/LinuxDesktop15/LinuxDesktop15.vbox
Snapshot folder: /Users/antkong/VirtualBox VMs/LinuxDesktop15/Snapshots
Log folder:      /Users/antkong/VirtualBox VMs/LinuxDesktop15/Logs
Hardware UUID:   8bfd870e-f770-429d-bbfc-13b26dffc81d
Memory size:     512MB
Page Fusion:     off
VRAM size:       16MB
CPU exec cap:    100%
HPET:            off
Chipset:         piix3
Firmware:        BIOS
Number of CPUs:  1
PAE:             off
Long Mode:       on
Synthetic CPU:   off
CPUID overrides: None
Boot menu mode:  message and menu
Boot Device (1): Floppy
Boot Device (2): DVD
Boot Device (3): HardDisk
Boot Device (4): Not Assigned
ACPI:            on
IOAPIC:          on
Time offset:     0ms
RTC:             UTC
Hardw. virt.ext: on
Nested Paging:   on
Large Pages:     on
VT-x VPID:       on
VT-x unr. exec.: on
State:           running (since 2015-06-16T01:36:17.297000000)
Monitor count:   1
3D Acceleration: off
2D Video Acceleration: off
Teleporter Enabled: off
Teleporter Port: 0
Teleporter Address: 
Teleporter Password: 
Tracing Enabled: off
Allow Tracing to Access VM: off
Tracing Configuration: 
Autostart Enabled: off
Autostart Delay: 0
Default Frontend: 
Storage Controller Name (0):            IDE
Storage Controller Type (0):            PIIX4
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  2
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      2
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
Storage Controller Name (1):            SATA
Storage Controller Type (1):            IntelAhci
Storage Controller Instance Number (1): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (1):  30
Storage Controller Port Count (1):      1
Storage Controller Bootable (1):        on
IDE (1, 0): /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso (UUID: 4dbd5fce-db20-4eba-b0ac-e5593aadb08f)
SATA (0, 0): /Users/antkong/VirtualBox VMs/LinuxDesktop15/LinuxDesktop15.vdi (UUID: 5249358d-1608-4f71-851c-5dbd75dd059a)
NIC 1:           MAC: 08002708DCB0, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 2:           disabled
NIC 3:           disabled
NIC 4:           disabled
NIC 5:           disabled
NIC 6:           disabled
NIC 7:           disabled
NIC 8:           disabled
Pointing Device: USB Tablet
Keyboard Device: PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:          disabled
UART 2:          disabled
LPT 1:           disabled
LPT 2:           disabled
Audio:           enabled (Driver: CoreAudio, Controller: AC97)
Clipboard Mode:  disabled
Drag'n'drop Mode: disabled
Session type:    GUI/Qt
Video mode:      720x400x0 at 0,0
VRDE:            disabled
USB:             enabled
EHCI:            enabled

USB Device Filters:

<none>

Available remote USB devices:

<none>

Currently Attached USB Devices:

<none>

Bandwidth groups:  <none>

Shared folders:  <none>

VRDE Connection:    not active
Clients so far:     0

Video capturing:    not active
Capture screens:    0
Capture file:       /Users/antkong/VirtualBox VMs/LinuxDesktop15/LinuxDesktop15.webm
Capture dimensions: 1024x768
Capture rate:       512 kbps
Capture FPS:        25

Guest:

Configured memory balloon size:      0 MB
OS type:                             Linux26_64
Additions run level:                 1
Additions version:                   4.3.22_Ubuntu r98236


Guest Facilities:

Facility "VirtualBox Base Driver": active/running (last update: 2015/06/16 01:36:42 UTC)
Facility "Seamless Mode": not active (last update: 2015/06/16 01:36:42 UTC)
Facility "Graphics Mode": not active (last update: 2015/06/16 01:36:42 UTC)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your screen clearly says:

```
   blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector....
```

The *dev sr0*, in Linux, is the CD/DVD reader. This means that your VM is trying to read squashfs not from the hard drive, where it presumably resides, but from the CD/DVD disk, which is, possibly, what you set it up to do during installation.

You should change the boot order so that the HDD precedes anything. But you should also make sure that the HDD exists, and that it is bootable, because the standard procedure is that, if no CD/DVD is found,then the booting process should move on to the HDD without further hesitations, and the fact that it doesn't makes me suspect that the HDD either is not there, or is not bootable.

At any rate, you can use the installation medium (USB or CD/DVD) to do either thing: boot from it, then select: *Try Ubuntu without installing it*.